# Wordpress editor classic/html switching using jquery failed

Tags: jquery, wordpress, editor

for some reason, i need to use jquery to switch wordpress editor based on certain criteria met after ajax return value.

when I want to switch to html editor and set this, the tabbing will change, but all other part fail to change.

```
jQuery('#wp-content-wrap').removeClass('tmce-active').addClass('html-active');
```

when I switch to tinymce, tabbing will change, but all other part of tiny mce won't load out.

```
jQuery('#wp-content-wrap').removeClass('html-active').addClass('tmce-active');
```

need jquery click to trigger exact same display like human manually mouse click.

any way?

[image: not the result that i want]

Answer (score 0):

found an easy way to resolve this, just need to simulate the button click.

```
jQuery('#content-html').trigger('click');
jQuery('#content-tmce').trigger('click');
```